# How to create multiline tooltip text in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to show tool tip text in multiple lines, but `setTitle()` method in [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt) is simply ignoring the `\n` character?

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the title property then it is not possible to have multi line tooltip. This is not a GWT problem, but a browser tooltip implementation/handling issue. If you really need to have a multi line tooltip then use [Popup panel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) or [DecoratedPopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedPopupPanel.html).

This will involve a little extra coding than just making a call to setTitle, but as a benefit you get complete control over how the tooltip is presented.

Comment: For this we have to add event handlers for every widget ..right?

Comment: Yes! Once to show and once again to hide the tooltip, ie. if you are not using autohide. You can use Mouse[Over/Out]Handler for this. 

Sounds like a lot of work :) But, If like me, you subclass input Widgets in your project and use these subclasses instead of GWT input widgets directly, then you can work out an elegant one time solution.

Comment: an alternative using css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641304/tooltips-for-gwt-tree-adding-mouseovers-to-nodes/18058618#18058618

Answer (score 1):

`setTitle` worked for me if I included a `\n` as a line separator.

Comment: Which component are you using in your tooltip panel. Try using a text area in your tooltip: you will be able to \n your text regardless of the GWT version.