# Tooltips for GWT tree: adding mouseovers to nodes

Tags: gwt, tree, mouseover, tooltip

I'm trying to add tooltips for the nodes of a Tree in GWT. As such, I'd like to add a mouseover listener for the nodes of a tree rather than on the tree itself.

The Treelistener interface seems to be what I want but this is now deprecated in lieu of the handler system. I don't quite understand how to get mouseover behaviour on the cell as I only seem to be able to add a MouseOverHandler to the tree itself.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TreeItem can contains a Widget object. So add a MouseOverHandler and a MouseOutHandler on a widget (i.e. a Label) and put the widget inside the TreeItem to add :

```
Label myItemContent = new Label("My content");
myItemContent.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

  public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
    // construct and/or open your tooltip
  }
});

myItemContent.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

  public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
    // close your tooltip

  }
});
//put your Label inside a TreeItem
TreeItem myItem = new TreeItem(myItemContent);
// let's assume that parentNode is an ItemTree
parentNode.addItem(myItem);
```

An other solution can be to use GwtQuery. GwtQuery allows to bind event handler to any DOM element :

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.$;

...

TreeItem myItem = new TreeItem("My content");
$(myItem.getElement()).hover(new Function() {

  //method called on mouse over
  public void f(Element e) {
      // construct and/or open your tooltip
  }

}, new Function() {

  //method called on mouse out
  public void f(Element e) {
      //close your tooltip
  }
});

parentNode.addItem(myItem);
```

Julien

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for. Thanks Julien!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to stick my neck out a bit here since I haven't actually used a `Tree` in GWT yet, but I see that the `TreeItem` class is a subclass of `UIObject`.  Any `UIObject` can have its `setTitle()` method called.  Under the hood, this method sets the standard HTML title attribute to be whatever string you pass into `setTitle()`.

This should give you the tooltip behavior you seek.  As an added bonus, the browser does all of the mouse event handling for you:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeItem;

public class TreeTest extends Composite {

    public TreeTest() {
        Tree root = new Tree();
        initWidget(root);
        TreeItem dogs = new TreeItem("canines");
        dogs.addItem("Fido").setTitle("faithful");
        dogs.addItem("Lassie").setTitle("starlet");
        dogs.addItem("Touser").setTitle("ruthless killer");
        root.addItem(dogs);

        TreeItem cats = new TreeItem("felines");
        cats.addItem("Boots").setTitle("needy");
        cats.addItem("Fabio").setTitle("aloof");
        cats.addItem("Mandu").setTitle("bob seger");
        root.addItem(cats);
    }


}
```

---

**Edit:**  Now let's imagine that you don't want to use the browser's built-in tool-tip mechanism described above, and that you would like to handle the mouse events yourself.

`TreeItem` might look, on the surface, as a non-starter.  After all, it inherits directly from `UIObject` and not from `Widget`.  (The key difference that a `Widget` adds to `UIObject` is, after all, the ability to handle events.  So one would think that we cannot add handlers to the TreeItem!)

While this is strictly true, notice that `TreeItem` gives us the following constructor:

```
public TreeItem(Widget widget)
```

When we make each instance, then, we can pass a real `Widget` into it (such as a `Label`, perhaps, or maybe your own `class MyWidget extends Composite`) and we can add event handlers directly to that:

```
    import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOutEvent;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOutHandler;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOverEvent;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOverHandler;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeItem;

    public class AnotherTreeTest extends Composite {

        public AnotherTreeTest() {
            Tree root = new Tree();
            initWidget(root);
            TreeItem dogs = new TreeItem("canines");
            makeItem(dogs,"Fido","faithful");
            makeItem(dogs,"Lassie","starlet");
            makeItem(dogs,"Touser","ruthless killer");
            root.addItem(dogs);

            TreeItem cats = new TreeItem("felines");
            makeItem(cats,"Boots","needy");
            makeItem(cats,"Fabio","aloof");
            makeItem(cats,"Mandu","bob seger");
            root.addItem(cats);
        }

        private void makeItem(TreeItem parent, String name, final String tip) {
            Label label = new Label(name);
            TreeItem animal = new TreeItem(label);
            label.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                    GWT.log("mouse over " + tip); // do something better here
                }

            });
            label.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
                    GWT.log("mouse out " + tip); // do something better here
                }

            });
            parent.addItem(animal);
        }

}
```

Note that there may be other ways to accomplish this that are less expensive.  If you have an enormous tree, then creating a `Widget` for each node can get expensive.  Then you might want to explore a more sophisticated way of dealing with your mouse events, perhaps by having one handler that checks to see which element it is in.

Comment: While that's definitely helpful, I'm looking to have different tooltips for each different node in the tree. This gives one tooltip for the entire tree, correct?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that a `TreeItem` is used to represent each node, so you should be able to call `setTitle()` on each one to give each a distinct tooltip.  Note that pretty much everything in GWT eventually inherits from `UIObject`, so this is a pretty universal rule.   Whenever you want a tooltip, go look at the [Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html) -- if you see `UIObject` in the chain of superclasses, you're good to go.

Comment: Ah thanks. Any idea about the main part of the question regarding mouse listeners?

Comment: I added another idea above for event handling.

Comment: easy solution for exactly my problem, great!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that I settled upon is to make use of CSS.

```
/**
 * @return a label with a CSS controlled popup
 */
public static Widget labelWithHTMLPopup(String text, String description)
{
    FlowPanel p = new FlowPanel();
    p.addStyleName("tooltipLabel");
    p.add(new Label(text));

    HTML contents = new HTML(description);
    contents.setStyleName("tooltip");
    p.add(contents);

    return p;
}
```

With accompanying css:

```
/*************** Tooltip **************/

div.tooltip
{
    display: none;

    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px outset black;
    left: 90%;  
    top: -20px;

    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px #555;       
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    font-size: 80%; 
    z-index: 99;
}

div.tooltipLabel
{
    position: relative;
}
div.tooltipLabel:hover div.tooltip
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Of course, you can change the style, add fades etc as you like.

Less javas/javascript and more css.